# Maximal space without isolated points

Tags: general-topology

Following Bourbaki let us say that a topology on $X$ is quasi-maximal if it is maximal in the set of topologies in which $X$ has no isolated point.

Bourbaki gives the following exercise: if $X$ is a Kolmogorov space (that is a $T_0$-space) in which every non-empty open set is infinite, then there is a quasi-maximal topology on $X$ which is finer than the given topology on $X$.

But it seems to me that the set of topology without isolated points is inductive, so that the statement is obvious (by application of Zorn's lemma) because a space where every non-empty open set is infinite must be without isolated point.

Plus Bourbaki gives a hint: 1) prove that the set of topology such that every non-void open set if infinite is inductive; 2) use the fact that in a Kolmogorov space without isolated point, any non-void open set is infinite.

Am I wrong or is there a typo in the exercise?

Edit. I will try to make clear what I think is true. Let us say that a topology on $X$ has property $(Q)$ (resp. $(P)$) if any non-void open set is infinite (resp. if $X$ has no isolated point).

1. It is clear that $(Q)\Rightarrow(P)$ and if $X$ is $T_0$ it is easy to show that $(P) \Rightarrow (Q)$ as well.
2. If $X$ has $(P)$, there is some finer topology $\mathcal T$ which has property $(P)$ and is maximal (in the usual sense). This follows from Zorn's lemma. Bourbaki calls quasi-maximal such a maximal topology.
3. Likewise, if $X$ has $(Q)$ there is some finer topology which has $(Q)$ and is maximal: Zorn's lemma again.

So the fact that given some $T_0$ space having property $(Q)$, there is a finer quasi-maximal topology, is a particular case of 2, because $(Q)\Rightarrow (P)$.

We can also prove it in the following way: let $\mathcal T'$ be a finer topology, such that $\mathcal T'$ has $(Q)$ and is maximal (as in 3). Then $\mathcal T'$ has property $(P)$ as well (see 1). If $\mathcal T''$ is some topology finer than $\mathcal T'$ which has property $(P)$ as well, then $\mathcal T''$ is obviously $T_0$ so it has property $(Q)$ (see 1) and we conclude that $\mathcal T''=\mathcal T'$. So $\mathcal T'$ is quasi-maximal indeed but this is a long road for a very obvious result.

This is why I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the hint, I suspect that the exercise was supposed to be to show that if $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a $T_0$ space without isolated points, then there is a quasi-maximal topology $\tau'$ on $X$ such that $\tau\subseteq\tau'$.

Comment: But this fact does not depend on the hypothesis that $\tau$ is $T_0$, does it? Plus, it's an obvious application of Zorn lemma, isn't it?

Comment: @timofei: Yes, it does: the two-point space with the indiscrete topology has no isolated points, but every open set is finite. That’s why you need the second part of the hint. And since the first part of the hint is indeed very easy, so is the application of Zorn’s lemma.

Comment: The two-point space with trivial topology is quasi-maximal isn't it? And similarly if $X=\{0,1,2\}$ then there is a quasi-maximal topology finer than the trivial topology, namely $\{\varnothing,X,\{0,1\}\}$ for example (in fact there are 3 quasi-maximal topologies on this set).

Comment: @timofei: Possibly we’re talking about different facts. By *this fact* I understood you to mean the fact stated in part (2) of the hint. If you meant the conclusion of the theorem, then I agree with you. I was merely trying to reconstruct the intended exercise from the hint given. Whether the intended result is best possible is a separate issue.

Comment: Now I understand your answer, indeed we were not talking about the same. I edited the first post to make things more clear (hopefully).